# DAG scheduler Event Loop outOfMemoryerror: Java Heap Space with Spark Streaming Application

Tags: apache-spark, out-of-memory

My Spark Streaming application continuous to fail with OutOfmemoryException: Java Heap Space.

I am using the below configuration for my Spark Submit Job.

```
spark-submit \
  --class ... \
  --master ...\
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --executor-memory 1G \
  --total-executor-cores 3 \
  --driver-memory 2G
```

and spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead is set to 1G .

After analysing the heap dump , i noticed excessive usage of "DAG scheduler Event Loop" and if i further look into it , i see CHAR[] and byte[] class be used.

The Old Generation GC occupies all 2GB of memory and continues to grow.

Please suggest of this is a bug or you need more information on the same to further analyse the same.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: How much data are you processing? 1G for a spark executor is a very low amount of memory. Don't forget that there's overhead needed for the JVM Runtime, you don't get the full 1G anyway. You need to beef up your executors memory.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in the usage of ForkJoinPool in Spark 2.0.0 which is creating way too many threads

This issue is resolved here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17396

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.